# Default conditions on Hibernate filters

Tags: java, hibernate, filter

I'm defining a Hibernate filter which specifies a default condition as follows:

```
<filter-def name="IsDeletedFilter" condition="IsDeleted = 'false'" />
```

Within my entity mapping, I associate the filter like this:

```
<filter name="IsDeletedFilter" />
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html), the filter should apply the default condition when used this way. When I try to do this, however, Hibernate throws a NullPointerException when it tries to parse the entity mapping. The stack trace shows this:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.parseFilter(HbmBinder.java:2957)

If, however, I specify the condition directly in the entity mapping like this:

```
<filter name="IsDeletedFilter2" condition="IsDeleted = 'false'"/>
```

it works fine and the data is getting filtered correctly.

What's the right way to use default conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. The possible walkaround is to define filters in another file, and include it. http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2488